# Button action to navigate another URL link in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I have a button code is given below.

```
new sap.ui.commons.Button("myButton2",{text:"Next",press:function(){







},style: sap.ui.commons.ButtonStyle.Emph })
```

when i press Next button it should navigate to new page

Can any one help me on this....

Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SAPUI5 Open link on Button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935407/sapui5-open-link-on-button-press)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go to external link you can use below code

```
window.location.replace("http://mywebsite.com/nextPage.html");
```

If you want to load a new view into the Shell, you could go for..

```
var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idSecondPage", viewName:"project.secondPage", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
oShell.setContent(view); // or oPanel.setContent()
```

for panels etc..

Comment: sorry to comment after 4 years, but  how can I make it possible to navigate back and forward again ? when I click on  my button now, it doesn't store the history...

Answer (score -1):

For better design, you need to setup multipage views. For mobile app, use m.app to handle pages. For web app, you need use .History to track pages.

Comment: Please can you expand on your answer, maybe with code examples? Thanks.