# SAPUI5 Open link on Button press

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 application and want to open a link if I click on a button.

I get the value of the specific link from an OData call and a normal `<Link>` control is working fine with the remote data path.

```xml
<Link href="{oData>/Url}" target="_blank" text="Click me" />
```

Tried several ways to open the website with a `<Button>` instead, but none of them were working for me.

I tried to put a Button inside of it.

```xml
<Link target="_blank" href="{oData>/Url}" text="Click me">
  <Button text="Open Website"/> <!-- Error: Cannot add direct child without default aggregation defined for control sap.m.Link -->
</Link>
```

But I'm getting the above error.

Tried using an HTML link, but it can't deal with the path of the remote data:

```html
<html:a href="{oData>/Url}" target="_blank"><Button text="Open Website"/></html:a>
```

[image: SAPUI5 app opened in SAP Web IDE with an invalid URL]

Then I tried to use the `onPress` event handler when using a Button and the `window.open` function:

```xml
<Button text="Open Website" press=".onPress" />
```

```js
{ // In the Controller
  onPress: function () {
    window.open("{oData>/Url}","_blank");
  },
}
```

But the Controller also can't deal with the path of the remote data resulting in the same invalid URL.

I also read from `URLHelper` and tried [this sample](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.URLHelper/sample/sap.m.sample.UrlHelper/code/List.controller.js), but I'm unable to add the "value" attribute to the Button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UI5 provides [`sap/m/library.URLHelper`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.URLHelper) for this.

```xml
<Button xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ sapMLib: 'sap/m/library' }"
  text="Open Website"
  press="sapMLib.URLHelper.redirect(${myModel>/Url}, ${myViewModel>/newTab})"
/>
```

#### Documentation

- API reference: [`sap.m.URLHelper.redirect`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.URLHelper#methods/sap.m.URLHelper.redirect)
- Section "Passing Parameters" from the topic ["Handling Events in XML Views"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b0fb4de7364f4bcbb053a99aa645affe) (since UI5 1.56)
- Topic ["Require Modules in XML View and Fragment"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b11d853a8e784db6b2d210ef57b0f7d7) (since UI5 1.69)

---

If the target URL needs to be further processed:

```xml
<Button text="Open Website" press=".openUrl(${myModel>/urlPart}, true)" />
```

```js
openUrl: function(urlPart, newTab) {
  const url = urlPart/*...*/;
  const { URLHelper } = sapMLib; // sapMLib required from "sap/m/library"
  URLHelper.redirect(url, newTab);
},
```

Comment: Hi Boghyon, this does not work on mobiles. It requires an element to be wrapped such like sap.m.Link, but I also have a requirement like Xuki, I need to link the URL to an icon. Would there be any suggestion on that?

Comment: @MerveGül Which mobiles with which UI5 versions have you tested? Are samples from https://sdk.openui5.org/entity/sap.m.URLHelper working?

Comment: Hi Boghyon, yes the samples link works as expected. It is iphone 14 with sap ui5 1.115.0. I have a button with press event bound to a function. In this function, I make a callFunction to retrieve the location data (because at the end we want to display it on google maps). And the callFunction success and error callbacks are also bound to 2 separate functions. In the success callback function I call the URLHelper.redirect with the calculated url. It works perfectly fine on desktop but on mobile does not respond.

Comment: @MerveGül The samples from the Demo Kit are practically same as the code in the answer above. I suspect the issue is somewhere else. Would be nice if you could create a new question with details on how to reproduce the issue - if possible with the device emulation on Chrome desktop. Are you using an `sap.ui.core.Icon` instead of `sap.m.Button`?